# How to make border larger on WordPress Teams plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, formatting

I'm trying to make a website i'm working on look like how it does on desktop or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to your page and used the webdev tools to make adjustments. A revisit could get your layout to work as you expected using flex-box or inline-block.

But a quick fix here would be to watch how you use %. Anything more than 100% will make elements appear larger than their parent elements.

The box that is too narrow is set to 22% and should be set to 'auto'.

I added `no-repeat 50% 50% / cover` to your background image div and made it's width 30%.

There's a lot going on here that contributes to this, but hopefully, this gets you to a better place.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a ton, I weeded a lot of my custom CSS since it was unnecessary to put it in. It now works on all platforms flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

It works better without that css-code. Try to remove it.
I don't know hat you want to accieve with it.

I would suggest not using % to avoid getting random shapes.

Comment: Don't use % over 100%, your problem i that the container is to small. Try to change that  first. Are you aware that you have two competing ways of managing responsiveness to smaller screens? Both the "col-*, -xs*" classes, and also your custom media queries.Go through your code, and clean up a bit.

Comment: whenever I try to change the container, i get a ton of white space off the page. 100% is too small somehow